# getting the even index of a string

Tags: php

hey guys im trying to get the even indexes of a string from the db then save them in a variable then echo. but my codes seems doesnt work. please help. here it is

```
require_once('DBconnect.php');
$school_id = '1';
$section_id = '39';
$select_pk = "SELECT * FROM section 
    WHERE school_id = '$school_id' 
    AND section_id = '$section_id'";
$query = mysql_query($select_pk) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $public_key = $row['public_key'];
}

if ($public_key) {
    $leng_public_key = strlen($public_key);
    $priv_key_extract = "";
    $array_pki = array();
    for ($i=0; $i <=$leng_public_key-1 ; $i++) { 
        array_push($array_pki,$public_key[$i]);
    }

    foreach ($array_pki as $key  => $value) {
        if($key % 2 == 0) {
            $priv_key_extract += $public_key[$key];
        } else {
            $priv_key_extract ="haiiizzz";
        }
    }
}
echo $priv_key_extract;
```

as you can see im trying to use modulo 2 to see if the index is even.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which.

Comment: we started the project with mysql_* but then ill be switching into mysqli after this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated your code as below, it will work now :

```
<?php
$public_key = 'A0L8V1I5N9';
if ($public_key) {
    $leng_public_key = strlen($public_key);
    $priv_key_extract = "";
    $array_pki = array();
    for ($i=0; $i <=$leng_public_key-1 ; $i++) {
        array_push($array_pki,$public_key[$i]);
    }
    foreach ($array_pki as $key  => $value) {
        //Changed condition below $key % 2 ==0 => replaced with $key % 2 == 1
        if($key % 2 == 1) {
            // Changed concatenation operator , += replaced with .=
            $priv_key_extract .= $public_key[$key];
        } /*else {
            //Commented this as it is getting overwritten
            $priv_key_extract ="haiiizzz";
        }*/
    }
}
echo $priv_key_extract;
?>
```

Comment: Ha, I think I get misunderstanding @Aoi

Comment: i forgot that .= is diff from += in php

Comment: @Minesh why did you change  if($key % 2 == 1) from  if($key % 2 == 0) got confused

Comment: @Aoi Because you are trying to extract 08159 from A0L8V1I5N9, so it has to be extracting all odd characters, not even.

A = 0th position (EVEN), 0 = 1st position (ODD), L = 2nd (even), 8 =3rd (Odd) like that...

Comment: ahhh.. ok now i get it tnx.

Answer (score 0):

Try this function

```
function extractKey($key) {
    if (empty($key) || !is_string($key)) return '';

    $pkey = '';
    for ($i=0;$i<strlen($key);$i++) {
        if ($i % 2 == 0) {
            $pkey .= $key[$i];
        }
    }
    return $pkey;
}
echo extractKey('12345678'); # => 1357
```